# This Node.js program is working, It uses serialport, and ws

Tags: node.js, arduino, raspberry-pi3

The project boards are:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- Arduino Uno rev3

The Git file: https://github.com/artikcloud/sample-iot-MonitorFlameTemp

```js
var webSocketUrl = "wss://api.artik.cloud/v1.1/websocket?ack=true";
var device_id = "<00840e8c030c4482b29c01bb431aa41ee>";
var device_token = "<9e973185912d4680b8cbaa34098c7f67>";

var isWebSocketReady = false;
var ws = null;

var serialport = require("serialport")
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", {
    baudrate: 9600,
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});

var WebSocket = require('ws');

/**
 * Gets the current time in millis
 */
function getTimeMillis(){
    return parseInt(Date.now().toString());
}

/**
 * Create a /websocket bi-directional connection 
 */
function start() {
    //Create the websocket connection
    isWebSocketReady = false;
    ws = new WebSocket(webSocketUrl);
    ws.on('open', function() {
         console.log("Websocket connection is open ....");
         register();
    });
    ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
         console.log("Received message: " + data + '\n');
    });
    ws.on('close', function() {
         console.log("Websocket connection is closed ....");
    });
}

/**
 * Sends a register message to the websocket and starts the message flooder
 */
function register(){
    console.log("Registering device on the websocket connection");
    try{
        var registerMessage = '{"type":"register", "sdid":"'+device_id+'", "Authorization":"bearer '+device_token+'", "cid":"'+getTimeMillis()+'"}';
        console.log('Sending register message ' + registerMessage + '\n');
        ws.send(registerMessage, {mask: true});
        isWebSocketReady = true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error('Failed to register messages. Error in registering message: ' + e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * Send one message to ARTIK Cloud
 */
function sendData(onFire){
    try{
        ts = ', "ts": '+getTimeMillis();
        var data = {
                    "onFire": onFire
                   };
        var payload = '{"sdid":"'+device_id+'"'+ts+', "data": '+JSON.stringify(data)+', "cid":"'+getTimeMillis()+'"}';
        console.log('Sending payload ' + payload);
        ws.send(payload, {mask: true});
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error in sending a message: ' + e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * All start here
 */

start(); // create websocket connection

sp.on("open", function () {
    sp.on('data', function(data) {
            if (!isWebSocketReady){
                console.log("Websocket is not ready. Skip sending data to ARTIK Cloud (data:" + data +")");
                return;
            }
            console.log("Serial port received data:" + data);
            var flameDigitalValue = parseInt(data);

            // flameDigitalValue = 1 ==> no fire is detected
            // flameDigitalValue = 0 ==> fire is detected
            var onFire = false;
            if (flameDigitalValue == 0) {
               onFire = true;
            }
            sendData(onFire);
    });
});
```

And for some reason it is not working I got the code from this website: https://www.artik.io/blog/2016/05/monitor-fire-temperature-using-artik-cloud-open-source-iot-hardware-android/

But is is giving me this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ node index.js
/home/pi/index.js:12
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
                               ^

TypeError: serialport.parsers.readline is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/index.js:12:32)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears that the parsers have been split out from the serialport library into their own module.  You will probably have to install and `require()` them separately.  See the [serialport doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) for info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serialport module (the parser implementation) has changed after version 4.x.

You have 2 options.

a) downgrade your serialport module; if you know which version number has been used (ask author of the GitHub project)

```
npm uninstall serialport
npm install serialport@<version>
```

b) upgrade your code to current version of the serialport module (usage of parser), see https://node-serialport.github.io/parsers/ReadLineParser.html

Looking at your code you need to replace the serial port creation with something like this:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = require('parser-readline');
const sp = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyACM0', {
        baudRate: 9600
});
const parser =  sp.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: "\n"}));
```

Note, in end of your code you need to replace

```
sp.on('data' ...
```

with

```
parser.on('data' ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would recommend option (b), btw.